# Export pandas dataframe to google drive in colaboratary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

```
sentmaildt1 = seriessplit(sentmail,'Sent_date',('sentmail_date','sentmail_time')," ")

sentmaildt1.to_csv("sentmaildt1.csv", columns = sentmaildt1.columns)

from google.colab import files

files.download('sentmaildt1.csv')
```

I did a basic operation on my sentmail dataframe (4 million x 5) and stores this in other dataframe sentmaildt1. Now I want to get this in csv and download to local system. Following error occurred:

> Error: Failed to download:

I want this csv to go to my linked google drive. I read all my csv files from drive using pydrive. I want to store output there too.

Comment: Is "sentmaildt1.csv" an actual file or is it a blob file or what not?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to save a DataFrame to your Google Drive:

```
df.to_csv("example.csv")
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'name.csv'})
uploaded.SetContentFile("example.csv")
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))}
```

If you want to download it to your local system:

```
df.to_csv("example.csv")
files.download()
```

Comment: To me the only difference was: files.download("example.csv").

Comment: Can't we directly push it to drive? Without converting it into csv?

Comment: Which library do we need to import for drive function